# How to discern the scope of a question?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I post a question and it's not banned nor deleted (thank god) just edited, and I thank that btw. Just a question for self-improvement. Most edits are that a tag for example is not appropiate, even when there's a technology involved. I analyzed it a bit, and the specific fix that I ask for the problem was on the scope of a certain technology (Example: It's a java app on a WAS server, and the question is about how to receive acknowledgement JMS, so it falls under Java according to the editors, not to Websphere)

I'm not asking for an absolute solution, but maybe there's some guideline I'm missing here. How would you discern the difference more easily? (So I can avoid this mistake, for future postings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the test for if a tag should be used would be if you take that out would you still have the same problem.

For example, I spend a lot of time on [android](/questions/tagged/android). A lot of people want to use [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) if they are using the Eclipse IDE to develop. This should only be used if it is specific to the Eclipse IDE. So, if they would still be having the same issues, errors, etc... using IntelliJ, AS, or something similar then that tag is not needed and can lead to confusion often times.

So, in your example, if the same issue you were having would still occur if you were using a different technology then that tag might not be necessary where [java](/questions/tagged/java) definitely would be.

Comment: In the example I use both websphere and Java. websphere is the server where I deploy and Java the technology of the app being deployed. But the fix asked is something Java-related. I usually put websphere because I think that it may be pertinent to the question, but I ask about the language. You gave me an idea there, so before putting a tag, we have to know beforehand (in some extent) that the answer is necesary related to the tagged technology, right? (If the answer is gonna be something on Java, then java tag, if it also has something websphere-related, websphere tag). Something like that?

Comment: Exactly. That's how I look at it. If in doubt, then I would recommend being safe and put the extra tag, as long as you aren't doing it hastily. Just don't be offended when it is edited (which it doesn't sound like you are). But, yes if you think it might have something to do with that other technology then by all means, put the tag.